# How to change background color and button size of a finished script?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, colors

I received a ready-made script from a payment processing company, I want to increase the size of the button and the background color, I've tried it with html but it doesn't work

```html
<script data-reference-id="2f334db3-3df2-46c2-93cd-fd2c05079acf">
  const s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = "https://static.dlocalgo.com/dlocalgo.min.js", s.async = !0, document.body.appendChild(s), s.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const e = document.querySelector('script[data-reference-id="2f334db3-3df2-46c2-93cd-fd2c05079acf"]'),
      t = e.parentNode,
      n = "dp-btn-2f334db3-3df2-46c2-93cd-fd2c05079acf",
      c = document.createElement("div");
    c.id = n, t.insertBefore(c, e);
    new DlocalGo("wPvxvAjzGSlDGrYLQDamRXkTDKvsEDyc").createCheckout(n, {
      country: "UY",
      currency: "UYU",
      amount: "17000",
      lang: "",
      text: "quiero inscribirme"
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: add css `#dp-btn-2f334db3-3df2-46c2-93cd-fd2c05079acf_button` which `dp-btn-2f334db3-3df2-46c2-93cd-fd2c05079acf` from your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Changing the background color and size is related with styling which we can do with CSS.
- ALl you need is add your custom class and apply style using that **class selector.**

```js
c.classList.add("my-btn-container"); // we are adding our own class to apply CSS
```

```css
:root {
  --your-color: #44cc44;
}

.my-btn-container .DlocalGoButton {
  background-color: var(--your-color);
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script data-reference-id="2f334db3-3df2-46c2-93cd-fd2c05079acf">
  const s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = "https://static.dlocalgo.com/dlocalgo.min.js", s.async = !0, document.body.appendChild(s), s.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const e = document.querySelector('script[data-reference-id="2f334db3-3df2-46c2-93cd-fd2c05079acf"]'),
      t = e.parentNode,
      n = "dp-btn-2f334db3-3df2-46c2-93cd-fd2c05079acf",
      c = document.createElement("div");
    c.classList.add("my-btn-container"); // we are adding our own class to apply css
    c.id = n, t.insertBefore(c, e);
    new DlocalGo("wPvxvAjzGSlDGrYLQDamRXkTDKvsEDyc").createCheckout(n, {
      country: "UY",
      currency: "UYU",
      amount: "17000",
      lang: "",
      text: "quiero inscribirme"
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I need to put this button inside WP Elementor, I have the option of indexing an html code, is this possible with the code you made?

Comment: In elementor you can add class name as well so you do not need to ad js just add classname and apply css

Comment: Is there a way to convert it to an inline code? Can you give me a hint? I already tried the class option in Elementor and it didn't work

Comment: do you how you can attch your external CSS to Elementor theme?

Comment: How do I insert the code you made into a box that accepts html codes?

Comment: use my ```<script>script code/script/>```  tag as it is and add css in ```<style>css code</style>``` tag

Comment: I put the tags and it didn't work, can you call me in chat?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73965578/i-need-to-put-this-code-inside-an-html-box-so-it-all-has-to-be-in-line-but-css

Comment: To change the size of the text inside the button, do I have to create another class?

Comment: No just use ```font-style``` property.

Comment: And please have a look how I updated your new question and you will get idea where I have putten CSS and relocate line in js

Comment: You are welcome, are you learning or working?

Comment: Learning and working ;)  and looking for more work

Answer (score 0):

One way is to target the outer container using it's data attribute, which is unlikely to change (I think). You can further refine the CSS to targe the first button (if you like).

```
[data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded] button:first-child {
    ... css stuff
```

```css
[data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded] button:first-child {
  padding: 50px;
  background: rgb(131, 58, 180);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(131, 58, 180, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%, rgba(252, 176, 69, 1) 100%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script data-reference-id="2f334db3-3df2-46c2-93cd-fd2c05079acf">
  const s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = "https://static.dlocalgo.com/dlocalgo.min.js", s.async = !0, document.body.appendChild(s), s.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const e = document.querySelector('script[data-reference-id="2f334db3-3df2-46c2-93cd-fd2c05079acf"]'),
      t = e.parentNode,
      n = "dp-btn-2f334db3-3df2-46c2-93cd-fd2c05079acf",
      c = document.createElement("div");
    c.id = n, t.insertBefore(c, e);
    new DlocalGo("wPvxvAjzGSlDGrYLQDamRXkTDKvsEDyc").createCheckout(n, {
      country: "UY",
      currency: "UYU",
      amount: "17000",
      lang: "",
      text: "quiero inscribirme"
    })
  });
</script>
```