# I need to put this code inside an html box, so it all has to be in line, but css style does not load

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tags

The code below does not load the styles in the CSS inline, did I declare a tag wrongly?The code below does not load the styles in the CSS inline, did I declare a tag wrongly?
I need to put this code inside an html box, so it all has to be in line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<style>
   :root {
    --color: #44cc44;
  }
  
  .my-btn-container .DlocalGoButton {
    background-color: var(--color);
    padding: 15px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <center>
    <script data-reference-id="2f334db3-3df2-46c2-93cd-fd2c05079acf">
      const s = document.createElement("script");
      s.src = "https://static.dlocalgo.com/dlocalgo.min.js", s.async = !0, document.body.appendChild(s), s.addEventListener("load", () => {
        const e = document.querySelector('script[data-reference-id="2f334db3-3df2-46c2-93cd-fd2c05079acf"]'),
          t = e.parentNode,
          n = "dp-btn-2f334db3-3df2-46c2-93cd-fd2c05079acf",
          c = document.createElement("div");
        c.classList.add("my-btn-container");
        c.classList.add("my-btn-container"); // we are adding our own class to apply css
        c.id = n, t.insertBefore(c, e);
        new DlocalGo("wPvxvAjzGSlDGrYLQDamRXkTDKvsEDyc").createCheckout(n, {
          country: "UY",
          currency: "UYU",
          amount: "17000",
          lang: "",
          text: "quiero inscribirme"
        })
      });
    </script>

  </center>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to reference a variable, which I don't think is your intention:

```
.my-btn-container .DlocalGoButton {
  background-color: var(#44cc44); /*--Here, remove var()*/
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: You are a genius! :) thank you very much, I was looking for this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you using javascript inside this `style` tag here?

```html
<style>c.classList.add("my-btn-container");
```

Did you try using pure css in the whole `style` tag? Try declaring something simple to check if it's working at first, then work your way further, for example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test body color</h1>
</body>

<style>
body {
  color: red;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't find the error, the button should be green

Comment: It'll help in the future if you describe the problem more specifically, for example instead of "The code below does not load the styles in the CSS" you can ask "Why is my button not green after I'm trying to declare it green in css like this" :) Happy someone was able to help though!